# Document.GetElementById(VARIABLE) not working, only works with strings

Tags: javascript, php

Im using a checkbox to activate some javascript which is supposed to get an element from the page and change it. The issue is that when I use document.getElementID(x) it returns a null value, however when i replace x with the id hard-coded it works fine. The issue is that I want it to not be hard-coded as the page is dynamic.

I have already checked whether the variable x is assigned and that the element has an ID assigned to it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateInputsLabels(e){


        if(e.checked){
            //If True

            var value = 'quantity_' + e.value;

            var x = document.getElementById(value);// this is what doesnt work unless I hard-code the ID value 

            console.log(x);


        }else {
            //if false
            var cellUnchecked = document.getElementById(e.value);


        }



    }

</script>
```

```
// FULL HTML

<?php

if(isset($order)){
    $status = true;
}else $status = false;

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function updateInputsLabels(e){


        if(e.checked){
            //If True

            var value = 'quantity_' + e.value;

            var x = document.getElementById(value);

            console.log(x);


        }else {
            //if false
            var cellUnchecked = document.getElementById(e.value);


        }



    }

</script>


<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Main Content -->
    <div id="content">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show"  style="display:none;"  role="alert" id="fillFields">
                            <strong>Error!</strong> Please ensure all fields are filled in.
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>


                        <div class="p-5">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4"> <?=($status) ? 'Edit Order' : 'Create an Order'?></h1>
                            </div>
                            <form class="user" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateCustomerForm()" name="createEditCustomer">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <p><b>Customer</b></p>
                                        <select class="form-control" id="customer" onchange="customerID()" name="order[customer_id]" required>


                                            <option value="">-- Please Select a Customer ---</option>

                                            <?php foreach($customers as $customer){

                                                if($customer['customer_id'] == $order['customer_id']){


                                                    echo "  <option value=" . $customer['customer_id'] . " selected>" . $customer['customer_id'] . " " . $customer['first_name'] . ' ' . $customer['surname'] .  "</option>";



                                                }else {

                                                    echo "  <option value=" . $customer['customer_id'] . ">" . $customer['customer_id'] . " " . $customer['first_name'] . ' ' . $customer['surname'] .  "</option>";

                                                }
                                            }?>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3 mb-sm-0">

                                        <div class="table-responsive">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                                <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                                    <th>Price (VAT)</th>
                                                    <th>Quantity Avaliable</th>
                                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                                    <th>Total</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tfoot>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th>Product Name</th>
                                                    <th>Price (VAT)</th>
                                                    <th>Quantity Avaliable</th>
                                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                                    <th>Total</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                </tfoot>
                                                <tbody>


                                               <?php foreach($products as $row){?>
                                                    <tr id="row_<?=$row['product_id']?>">


                                                        <?php


                                                        if ($status && in_array($row['product_id'], $orderItems)) {

                                                            $location = array_search($row['product_id'], $orderItems);
                                                            unset($orderItems[$location]);

                                                            ?>
                                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="<?=$row['product_id']?>" onchange="updateInputsLabels(this)" checked></td>

                                                            <?php

                                                        }else echo " <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"product[]\" value=\" " . $row['product_id'] . "\" onchange=\"updateInputsLabels(this)\"></td>";?>



                                                        <td><?=$row['product_id'] . ' ' . $row['product_name']?></td>
                                                        <td><?=$row['product_price_vat']?></td>
                                                        <td><?=$row['quantity']?></td>
                                                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[<?=$row['product_id']?>]" id="quantity_<?=$row['product_id']?>"  onchange="updateTotal(this)" value="0"></td>
                                                        <td>

                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_<?=$row['product_id']?>"  name="total[<?=$row['product_id']?>]" value="0" disabled>

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                               <?php } ?>

                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <p><b>Additional Details</b></p>

                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea3"   name="order[order_details]" rows="5" required>

                                            <?=($status) ? $order['order_details'] : ''?>

                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                            <label for="validationDefaultUsername"><b>Discount</b></label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">%</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <input type="number" class="form-control " id="validationDefaultUsername"  name="order[discount]" placeholder="Percentage" value="" min="1" max="100"  aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" required>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <label for="validationDefaultUsername"><b>Total:</b></label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total"  name="order[total_price]"  aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" disabled>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-user" name="order[order_id]" placeholder="Address Line 2" value="<?=($status) ? $order['order_id'] : ''?>" required>

                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-user" name="order[staff_id]" placeholder="Address Line 2" value="<?=($status) ? $order['staff_id'] : $_SESSION['user']?>" required>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" style="  border-radius: 40px;" name="submit">Save</button>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Main Content -->

</div>
<!-- End of Main Content -->
```

Comment: What is final value of `var value`? Does this element exists?

Comment: Can you also share markup so we can see what the value is and what corresponding elements are?

Comment: can you share your checkbox code

Comment: Share your html please

Comment: `value` doesn't contain what you think it contains. Which also *must* be your own conclusion, so why haven't you tried logging `e.value` for instance? Please create a [mre] (emphasis on "minimal").

Comment: I have tried e.value same thing. The only time it works is if I just write manually write the value e.g. document.getElementById("1")

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a more generic event listener and not using an inline handler as here. If you use `querySelectorAll` you do not need to use `getElementById` which, in many instances, is very inconvenient. As the javascript function above does not yet appear to do very much perhaps you might try an approach like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach( chk=>{
    chk.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
        if( this.checked ){
            alert( this.value )
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What goes in the e.value?

It does not contain direct value of the checkbox. 
This works fine

```
  console.log(e.value)
  var value = 'quant_' + 1;
  var x = document.getElementById(value);
  console.log(x, 'hello');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5dom7wx8/16/

Comment: well the e.value is the value of the checkbox which in my case is the same value as the ID of the element im trying to fetch.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the code itself, in order for it to what what you explain, you should pass to the method updateInputsLabels the id of the input (i assume) you want to change:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="<?=$row['product_id']?>" onchange="updateInputsLabels('<?=$row['product_id']?>')" checked></td>
```

And change your method:

```
function updateInputsLabels(inputId){


    if(typeof inputId='string' && inputId.length > 0){
        let fullId = 'quantity_' + inputId;
        let element = document.getElementById(fullId );
        console.log(fullId );


    }else {
        console.error("not a string or empty");
    }
}
```